# Pandas: how to iteratively drop columns where column name contains two of the strings in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `data_raw` with 500 columns. I also have a list that contains target variables called `target_variables`.
`target_variables = ['snd', 'bounce', 'rock']`.

Here is how `data_raw` looks like (limited view as the data is confidential and too big to show here):

```
import pandas as pd
data_raw = pd.DataFrame(
{'date':[0, 0, 0], 'survey_date':[1, 2, 3], 'trackname':['a','b','c'], 
'min_snd':[0,0,0], 'median_snd':[0,0,0], 'mean_snd':[0,0,0], 'snd_percentile_95th':[0,0,0], 'max_snd':[0,0,0], 
'min_block':[0,0,0], 'median_block':[0,0,0], 'mean_block':[0,0,0], 'block_percentile_95th':[0,0,0], 'max_block':[0,0,0], 
'min_round':[0,0,0], 'median_round':[0,0,0], 'mean_round':[0,0,0], 'round_percentile_95th':[0,0,0], 'max_round':[0,0,0]})
```

What I am trying to do is make a dataframe containing the filtered column names from `data_raw` column names, called `target_variable_params`. The idea is that the first column of `target_variable_params` will be called `snd` and the rows will be all column names from `df` that do not contain the words `['bounce', 'rock']` and so forth (it will have three columns and 496 rows as each of `target_variables = ['snd', 'bounce', 'rock']` have 4 columns that contain the respective word).

This is what I have done, but it is not quite right:

```
target_variables = ['snd', 'bounce', 'rock']
target_variable_params = pd.DataFrame()

for target in target_variables:
    target_variables = ['snd', 'bounce', 'rock']
    target_variable_params.loc[:,target] = data_raw.drop(data_raw.filter(like='{}'.format(target)).columns, axis=1).columns
```

and this is what I am getting:
[image]

To be more clear, under `snd` I do not want to see `bounce, rock` columns.

But the ideal output would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Please provide some data as plain text.

Comment: @Corralien the data is confidential and too big. I can upload a snippet of how it looks

Comment: Not a problem. Create a sample as plain text and the expected result for this sample.

Comment: Just updated - thanks mate

Comment: Do I have to retype all the data by hand and guess if I get the right result? Please do not use image (except for the expected result if you prefer)

Comment: You are right mate, I will fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to get the result your question asks about:

```py
import pandas as pd
data_raw = pd.DataFrame(
{'date':[0, 0, 0], 'survey_date':[1, 2, 3], 'trackname':['a','b','c'], 
'min_snd':[0,0,0], 'median_snd':[0,0,0], 'mean_snd':[0,0,0], 'snd_percentile_95th':[0,0,0], 'max_snd':[0,0,0], 
'min_block':[0,0,0], 'median_block':[0,0,0], 'mean_block':[0,0,0], 'block_percentile_95th':[0,0,0], 'max_block':[0,0,0], 
'min_round':[0,0,0], 'median_round':[0,0,0], 'mean_round':[0,0,0], 'round_percentile_95th':[0,0,0], 'max_round':[0,0,0]})
print(data_raw)
newCols = ('snd', 'block', 'round')
data = list(zip(*[[c for c in data_raw.columns if all(y not in c for y in [z for z in newCols if z != x])] for x in newCols]))
target_variable_params = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=newCols)
print(target_variable_params)
```

Output:

```
   date  survey_date trackname  min_snd  median_snd  mean_snd  snd_percentile_95th  ...  block_percentile_95th  max_block  min_round  median_round  mean_round  round_percentile_95th  max_round
0     0            1         a        0           0         0                    0  ...                      0          0          0             0           0                      0          0
1     0            2         b        0           0         0                    0  ...                      0          0          0             0           0                      0          0
2     0            3         c        0           0         0                    0  ...                      0          0          0             0           0                      0          0

[3 rows x 18 columns]
                   snd                  block                  round
0                 date                   date                   date
1          survey_date            survey_date            survey_date
2            trackname              trackname              trackname
3              min_snd              min_block              min_round
4           median_snd           median_block           median_round
5             mean_snd             mean_block             mean_round
6  snd_percentile_95th  block_percentile_95th  round_percentile_95th
7              max_snd              max_block              max_round
```

Comment: @Amit Charkhi did this answer give you what you were looking for? Do you need any more help?